# Manipulating ActiveRecords using only a few attributes with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, memcached

For caching matters, I'm caching an array of the attributes of the objects I need:

```
friends = [{:id => 4, :name => "Kevin"}, {:id => 12, :name => "Martin"}, …]
```

Is it possible to have a list of Users using this array, so that I can use Ruby methods? For instance, I usually get a list of non-friends with this:

```
non_friends = User.all - current_user.friends
```

Here, current_user.friends would be replaced by the cached array, only with the cached attributes:

```
friends = [
    #<User id: 4, name: "Kevin", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, email: nil>,
    #<User id: 12, name: "Martin", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, email: nil>,
    …
]
```

Is it possible? Is it a good approach to caching? (a big list of ActiveRecords doesn't fit into a 1MB Memcache chunk.)

Thank you,

Kevin

**edit:** The idea behind this is to use a sorted/processed list of 2000 ActiveRecords around which my app heavily uses, but since it doesn't fit into a Memcache chunk, I'm trying to cache the interesting attributes only as an array. Now, how can I use this array like it was an ActiveRecord array?

Comment: What do you mean with "so I can use ruby methods"? Im not sure what you want to do? Maybe you should use another behavior than caching 10000 friends?

Comment: Ruby array methods, like "&" or "-" are very useful, but I can't compare an ActiveRecord array like `User.all` and an hash array like `[{:id => 1, :name => "Kevin"}, …]`

Comment: User.all.to_a - User.find(:all, :active => true).to_a works? :D And i dont get it.. Rails AR Collections have most of the array methods?

Comment: The problem is, User.all can't be cached. I want to replace User.all with something that can fit in cache, like a lighter array, but still be able to compare it with an array of ActiveRecords.

In other words: how to build an ActiveRecords array (the second 'friends' array) from a hash array (the first 'friends' array)?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can just cache the User IDs and then exclude these IDs in your finder conditions. In your example, assuming you have a `friends` array of hashes containing ids and names:

```
friend_ids = friends.map{ |f| f[:id] }
if friend_ids.empty?
  non_friends = User.all
else
  non_friends = User.all(:conditions => ['id NOT IN (?)', current_user.friend_ids])
end
```

Comment: I still have to query the database, but you are right, for less users than without the cache. I'll try this. Thanks :-)